# Do all methods of service installation on windows create a corresponding registry key?

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I'm trying to detect the installation of any service (both user mode and the kernel driver kind) on Windows.
As far as I know, this is possible in three ways:

- WINAPI: Using [CreateService()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) or similar functions
- Command Line: Using sc.exe create
- Registry: Directly adding a registry key with the corresponding values in one of the following paths:

  - [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services Registry Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-services-registry-tree)
  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices

Now according to the testing that I've done, both using the WINAPI and he command line way results in the creation of a corresponding registry key as a side effect.

Is it guaranteed that if a service has been created through whichever method, a corresponding registry key has been created under one of those paths? Can I rely on that?

Comment: if service or kernel mode driver is created - will created key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<somename>`

Comment: `sc create` is just a wrapper for `CreateService()`. The `RunServices` key (which only exists on Win9x/ME) is not an installation key, it merely runs installed processes as if they were services during startup before a user logs in. Actual services are only installed under the `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **Yes.** Windows utilizes reg entries to manage and run services. So any installed service will be in registry as it's required for it to work.

Long version: part of any service installation is adding a registry entry for it. It is absolutely needed for it to function. System uses the reg entry to know that there is such service, where is its executable and what is its status or settings are. Removing services reg entry essentially equals uninstalling it. It is likely backfire though on latest windows OS, so I would advise using different methods, like "sc delete" or services own uninstall method if one is included (servicename --uninstall for example, consult services manual for this info).

Comment: Of course, there's no absolute guarantee that the location and/or format of the registry keys in question won't move in future versions of Windows.  But I'd call it pretty unlikely.

Comment: That is correct, but in any occasion - services will end up having registry records somewhere if they are installed. Only way around making a registry entry I can think of: launching service via bat or autorun, but even this is not that simple, as in later windows versions it may require admin permissions, and with any security settings but lowest ones PC just can't run anything that requires admin privileges as autorun - you have to go and start it manually. It's been a great annoyance for me, as some of my apps just can't start on boot, but it is necessary security measure.

Comment: Oh, I can easily imagine Microsoft deciding it would be cooler if the service database was stored in an XML file or something.  But it would break too much existing code, and most of the time they try very hard not to do that.